# how to correctly map an obj and return a single value with several identical values ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently i have an array of object

I map this table

```
[
 { id: "a", location: "FR", zone: "EU" } ,
 { id: "b", location: "FR", zone: "EU" } , 
 { id: "c", location: "ES", zone: "EU" } , 
 { id: "d", location: "ES", zone: "EU" } ,
]
```

to sort all the data I use a useEffect to retrieve only the values ​​I need

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        const location = data.map((e) => {
            return {
                label: e.location,
            };
        });

        setLocations(locations);
    }
}, [data]);
```

this works correctly.

except which returns me the following format

```
0: {label: 'FR'}
1: {label: 'FR'}
2: {label: 'ES'}
4: {label: 'ES'}
```

and I would like to have the following format

```
  0: {label: 'FR'}
  1: {label: 'ES'}
```

basically it removes the identical key

iam open to any proposal thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array  check out the answer with like 5k upvotes in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `location` as an id-like property that determines the uniqueness, you can do:

```js
const data = [
  { id: "a", location: "FR", zone: "EU" } ,
  { id: "b", location: "FR", zone: "EU" } , 
  { id: "c", location: "ES", zone: "EU" } , 
  { id: "d", location: "ES", zone: "EU" } ,
];

console.log(
  Array
    .from(new Set(data.map(d => d.location)))  
    .map(label => ({ label }))
  
)
```

This first transforms the list to an array of strings. It uses a `Set` to get rid of duplicate strings. Then, it transforms to the desired output format.

- `data.map(d => d.location)` gives `[ "FR", "FR", "ES", "ES" ]`
- `Array.from(new Set(...))` gives `[ "FR", "ES" ]`
- `(...).map(label => ({ label }))` gives the final output

Answer (score 0):

use filter and indexOf

```js
data = data.filter(function (value, index, array) { 
  return array.indexOf(value) === index;
});
```